# how to find out the end of mp4 video in an embedded flash player

Tags: html, flash, embed, addeventlistener

I am trying to embed flash player in html. How do I find out that the video is done playing? My objective is to play another video after this is over. something like adding eventlistener.

```
<body > <div id="videoDiv" class="cls"></div></body>
<script>
var html = '<embed src="swfs/SampleMediaPlayback.swf" width=400 height=300  id="SampleMediaPlayback" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" name="SampleMediaPlayback"    allowfullscreen="true"  pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"    flashvars="&src="http://64.165.34.7:8134/vod/cupertino/nobacco.mp4"&autoHideControlBar=true&streamType=vod&autoPlay=false&verbose=true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>';
$("#videoDiv").html(html);
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? is this homemade video player ?

Comment: yes. I prepare the html according to the browser. Either <video> html5 or flash. I could add eventlistener to html5 but not being able to flash. Using adobe media server inherited flash player.

Comment: It really depends on the way SampleMediaPlayback.swf is coded, you should read its documentation if it exists. Otherwise you should find another video player you know is able to send an ExternalInterface command when the video is done playing.

Comment: SampleMediaPlayback.swf is provided by Adobe Media Server and there is no documentation available on this.